# How to fix iOS Over The Air Enterprise App Installation not showing app icon

Tags: php, ios, installation, plist, ota

Pre Note: I understand there are other questions like this however none had an accepted answer nor an answer that worked. I'd like the record to show I did try said answers and have come with more information to present a case.

Either Apple are lazy or not enough people have reported this issue so they haven't looked into it but found evidence that may suggest Apple are only allowing certain URLs to display images. Has anyone here had success in displaying app icons in OTA installations since iOS 10?

I am trying to get an enterprise signed application to show it's icon whilst installing. This used to be simple prior to the iOS 10 update.

Since iOS 10 nobody has even addressed this issue not even Apple has released a fix for it.

If you open Xcode and click Export IPA you'll see a generate manifest checkbox, if you press it and continue to the next screen you'll see a spot for your app icons.

This may mean two things:
1) Apple is lazy and forgot to remove it as it is now a defunct feature (Highly unlikely)
2) Not enough people have reported that OTA installation is broken when it comes to displaying app icons so Apple hasn't looked into it. (Plausible if you continue reading)

I was doing some research and found that if you use an app icon from Apple's server and use it in your install manifest that it'll display said icon perfectly fine but if you use an icon hosted on your own server (even if it's an icon downloaded from Apple's server and not modified) it will not show.

As shown in this screenshot: 
[image: Screenshot]

My Install Manifest code can be seen here (for my server): https://pastebin.com/0QgqDR24

```
 Check the PasteBin, this was required.
```

My Install Manifest code can be seen here (using my server for the IPA but Apple's Server for the icon): https://pastebin.com/Vn2ExyhZ

```
 Check the PasteBin, this was required.
```

Has anybody had success since iOS 10 with being able to have icons displayed during OTA App Installation?

Also, can apps still show the "Subtitle" when installing or is that actually defunct now?

Still looking for an answer :/

Comment: are you using the correct resolution image ? From the pastebin it seems like you are using 512X512 in apple server experiment and using 57x57 in your local server. I'm not sure whether it's the reason, but it can be.

Comment: Thought that may come up, when I was looking for answers someone suggested it could be the fact that they weren't using a 57x57 image as well as a 512x512 image, so I tried adding a 57x57 image but it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you add 512x512 for both ? I never tried the over installation using own server before, so not an expert in that area :)

Comment: Tried that as well, same issue.